# Spring Mysql com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I have created a table which has a column length varchar(1000); I could easily insert 800 character length string from workbench without any issue. But when I try the same string from my spring jpa application it gives below exception.

I use spring-data to save the object(JpaRepository). Below the java attribute in the entity.

```
  @Column(name = "site_area_detail", length = 5000) private String siteAreaDetail;



org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:282) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1159.saveWalkInBookingDetail(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at lk.pwc.cult.fund.services.citizen.app.controller.SiteGateController.saveWalkInTicketBooking(SiteGateController.java:77) ~[classes/:1.0]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117) [spring-boot-1.4.6.RELEASE.jar:1.4.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61) [spring-boot-1.4.6.RELEASE.jar:1.4.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:92) [spring-boot-1.4.6.RELEASE.jar:1.4.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-1.4.6.RELEASE.jar:1.4.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [catalina.jar:9.0.8]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:412) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.8]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.8]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.8]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1385) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.8]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.8]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.8]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:52) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2949) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3449) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.envers.internal.synchronization.AuditProcess.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcess.java:156) ~[hibernate-envers-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.envers.internal.synchronization.AuditProcessManager$1.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcessManager.java:46) ~[hibernate-envers-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:928) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:503) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2340) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
... 91 common frames omitted

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'site_area_detail' at row 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3833) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:1288) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:794) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2145) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2081) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2066) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-2.4.7.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.4.7.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
... 112 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, there could be an encoding thing going on here.  For example, Java strings are implicitly UTF-16 encoded, so maybe you had some UTF-8 content, for example, which ended up taking more than 1000 characters in your MySQL table.

Answer (score 3):

I have enabled auditing in my spring application. The error occurred from the audit table. I have increased the column length in the audit table column and now the issue is fixed. Thank you very much for everyone who helped.